# check for duplicates in all lists before moving item to list

Tags: php, list, duplicates, move

I have a master list populated from a master.csv file then I have multiple (10+) list populated from list1.csv, list2.csv, list3.csv ...etc. I want to move items from masterlist to list1 but need to check that item is not in any of the lists before it can be moved Herewith code but only use 3 list but there is more but I am unable to check for duplicates before move

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Move Items From Master List</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>

</head>

<select name=master[] id=master class="master" multiple="multiple" size='23'>
<?php   
    $file = fopen("temp.csv", "r");
    while (($row = fgetcsv($file, 0, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $master = $row[0];
?>
    <option><?php echo $master; ?></option>
<?php
    }
?>
</select> 

<form action="update.php" method="post">
    <input type=button class="master" name=b1 id=b1 value='Move >'>
    <input type=button class="master" name=b2 id=b2 value='< Remove'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<select name=list1[] id=list1 multiple="multiple" class=master>
<?php   
    $file = fopen("list1.csv", "r");
    while (($row = fgetcsv($file, 0, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $list1 = $row[0];
?>
    <option value="<?php echo $list1;?>"><?php echo $list1;?></option>
<?php
    }
?>
</select>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="submit" value="Save File" name="submit">
</form><br /><br />

<form action="update.php" method="post">
    <input type=button class="master" name=b3 id=b3 value='Move >'>
    <input type=button class="master" name=b4 id=b4 value='< Remove'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<select name=list2[] id=list2 multiple="multiple" class=master>
<?php   
    $file = fopen("list2.csv", "r");
    while (($row = fgetcsv($file, 0, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $list2 = $row[0];
?>
    <option value="<?php echo $list2;?>"><?php echo $list2;?></option>
<?php
    }
?>
</select>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="submit" value="Save File" name="submit">
</form>

 <script>
 $("#b1").click(function() {
    var source = $("#master");
    var target = $("#list1");
    $("option:selected", source).each(function() {
        target.append("<option>" + $(this).text() + "</option>");
        $("option[value= '" + $(this).val() + "' ]", source).remove();
    });
    $('option', target).prop('selected', true);
});

$("#b2").click(function(){
    var source = $("#list1");
    var target = "#master";
    $("option:selected", source).each(function() {
        master.append("<option>"+$(this).text()+"</option>");
        $("option[value= '"+ $(this).val() + "' ]", source).remove();
    });
    $('option', source).prop('selected', true);
});

$("#b3").click(function() {
    var source = $("#master");
    var target = $("#list2");
    $("option:selected", source).each(function() {
        target.append("<option>" + $(this).text() + "</option>");
        $("option[value= '" + $(this).val() + "' ]", source).remove();
    });
    $('option', target).prop('selected', true);
});

$("#b4").click(function(){
    var source = $("#list2");
    var target = "#master";
    $("option:selected", source).each(function() {
        master.append("<option>"+$(this).text()+"</option>");
        $("option[value= '"+ $(this).val() + "' ]", source).remove();
    });
    $('option', source).prop('selected', true);
});
    </script>
```

and my update.php file

```
<?php
header("Location:".$URL.'index.php');

if ($_POST['list1']) {
$list1 = $_POST['list1'];
$list1unique = array_unique($list1);
sort($list1unique);
foreach ($list1unique as $key => $value) {
    $result.=$value."\n";
}
file_put_contents('list1.csv',$result);
}

if ($_POST['list2']) {
$list2 = $_POST['list2'];
$list2unique = array_unique($list2);
sort($list2unique);
foreach ($list2unique as $key => $value) {
    $result.=$value."\n";
}
file_put_contents('list2.csv',$result);
}

?>
```